# Generate dynamic model using pydantic

Tags: python, pydantic

I am trying to create a dynamic model using Python's `pydantic` library. My input data is a regular `dict`. However, the content of the `dict` (read: its keys) may vary.
I am wondering how to dynamically create a `pydantic` model which is dependent on the `dict`'s content?

I created a toy example with two different `dict`s (`inputs1` and `inputs2`). Let's assume the nested `dict` called `strategy` may be different. Based on `strategy/name` I know in advance which fields will exist in `strategy`. I need to create the `pydantic` model based on `strategy/name`.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

inputs1 = {
    "universe": {"name": "test_universe", "ccy": "USD"},
    "price_src": "csv",
    "strategy": {"name": "test_strat1"},
}
inputs2 = {
    "universe": {"name": "test_universe", "ccy": "USD"},
    "price_src": "csv",
    "strategy": {"name": "test_strat2", "periods": 10},
}


class Universe(BaseModel):
    name: str
    ccy: str = "EUR"


strategy_name = "test_strat2"

if strategy_name == "test_strat1":
    inputs = inputs1

    class Strategy(BaseModel):
        name: str


elif strategy_name == "test_strat2":
    inputs = inputs2

    class Strategy(BaseModel):
        name: str
        periods: int


class StaticModel(BaseModel):
    universe: Universe
    price_src: str = "csv"
    strategy: Strategy


static_model = StaticModel(**inputs)
```

My expected output if ``strategy_name == "test_strat1":

```
universe=Universe(name='test_universe', ccy='USD') price_src='csv' strategy=Strategy(name='test_strat1')
```

My expected output if ``strategy_name == "test_strat2":

```
universe=Universe(name='test_universe', ccy='USD') price_src='csv' strategy=Strategy(name='test_strat2', periods=10)
```

I was thinking about using `pydantic`'s `create_model` function. However, I don't understand how to dynamically define the `fields`.

Comment: [**Pydantic Docs: Dynamic Model Creation**](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#dynamic-model-creation)

Answer (score 10):

For the dynamic creation of pydantic models, you can use [`create_model`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#dynamic-model-creation). Like so:

```
from pydantic import create_model

d = {"strategy": {"name": "test_strat2", "periods": 10}}

Strategy = create_model("Strategy", **d["strategy"])

print(Strategy.schema_json(indent=2))
```

Output:

```
{
  "title": "Strategy",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "title": "Name",
      "default": "test_strat2",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "periods": {
      "title": "Periods",
      "default": 10,
      "type": "integer"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mind to expand your solution with respect to the 1) How to define a ``str`` and ``int`` with no default values? and 2) Match my expected solutions in the way that ``strategy`` is nested.

Comment: Ad 1) ``Strategy = create_model("Strategy", **d)`` should give you the nested structure, shouldn't it?

Comment: I don't think it will be possible to create nested models, but you can experiment. As for removing the default values, you can try to use the syntax through the tuple specified in the documentation, like this `Strategy = create_model("Strategy", **{k: (type(v), ...) for k, v in d["strategy"].items()})`

Comment: why does it not support pass in a json schema and get a dynamic model? I see https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/integrations/datamodel_code_generator/#example can generate a model file by json schema.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `create_model` with `key=(type, ...)` (3 dots) to declare a field without default value. For example:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, create_model

...
if strategy_name == "test_strat1":
    inputs = inputs1
    Strategy = create_model('Strategy', name=(str, ...))

elif strategy_name == "test_strat2":
    inputs = inputs2
    Strategy = create_model('Strategy', name=(str, ...), periods=(int, ...))

print(Strategy.schema_json(indent=2))
```

Output for `test_strat1`:

```py
{
  ...
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "title": "Name",
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "name"
  ]
}
```

And for `test_strat2`:

```py
{
  ...
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "title": "Name",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "periods": {
      "title": "Periods",
      "type": "integer"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "name",
    "periods"
  ]
}
```

Related Pydantic documentation: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#dynamic-model-creation

You can see in the docs that:

- `foo=(str, ...)` - str-typed `foo` attribute with no defaults
- `bar=123` - int-typed `bar` attribute with a default value of `123`.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax has changed a bit in Pydantic 2.x:

```
d = {"name":(str, ...), "periods":(int, 0)}
Strategy = create_model("Strategy", **d)
```

You now want to pass tuples of **(TYPE, DEFAULT)** to the named parameters, or to make it fully dynamic, use a dictionary as shown above.